# Two Separate Systems on one Thermostat?

Tags: thermostat, heat

I have a baseboard hot water system and a separate gas furnace with heat and AC. Thus far, they have been on two separate thermostats. Is there a way to put them on one thermostat or is there a thermostat brand/model that is built for this?

Comment: How do you want them to operate together?

Comment: Anything’s possible, but it may not make much sense given that forced air gas is quicker to react, and hot water baseboard heat takes longer to make gains.

Comment: The separate systems were put in for some reason.  They are serving some separate function.  Dedicated thermostats make sense.  Given that they are already there, what do you see gaining by taking one out?

Comment: Do they heat separare parts of the house?  Is one particularly more efficient than the other?  Can each fully heat your house alone? How does the hot water system make heat and does it do anything else?